# Current user's Digital Certificate location StoreLocation

Tags: asp.net, iis, x509certificate

Good Morning! Does anyone know how to tell me why I can not use the StoreLocation.CurrentUser parameter to find a certificate using Asp.Net?

Comment: What happens when you try & whats the issue with the result? What CurrentUser do you want? The current App Pool account? A Windows Auth'd user?

Comment: The StoreLocation.CurrentUser only returns me the certificate when I am running the application via IISExpress. Already using Local IIS, the StoreLocation.CurrentUser returns null. I am using IIS anonymous authentication.

Comment: The reason is simple. On your machine there are multiple stores, and when the web app is running on IIS, the same code reads the machine store (as the machine account is the current user), while on IIS Express it reads your personal store. Typical Windows 101, and you need to find good Windows books/resources to learn more.